# Sort an HTML List Based on a String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of files displayed on my webpage that are organized in order of the date they were created. The file names display in the following format.

```
file_1_abc_10-23-2015.txt
file_2_fff_10-25-2015.txt
file_88_xyz_11-15-2015.txt
file_42_abc_11-17-2015.txt
file_9_ttt_11-25-2015.txt
```

I want to organize them based on a phrase they contain - in this case I want to sort by the third string phrase in the file name, so the sorted list would look like this

```
file_1_abc_10-23-2015.txt
file_42_abc_11-17-2015.txt
file_2_fff_10-25-2015.txt
file_9_ttt_11-25-2015.txt
file_88_xyz_11-15-2015.txt

//abc > abc > fff > ttt > xyz
```

I'm not sure whether this should be tackled with a front end script like jquery, or if this can be accomplished with a templating engine (I'm using thymeleaf, but I don't want to taylor this as a thymeleaf question because the output list is just basic HTML). I've just begun with this task and don't want to overkill it - Any thoughts?

Thanks much

Comment: you can do it using a simple js script.

Comment: How are you getting that list? Is it just an array sent to the client?

Comment: So, Kurai, does my answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list of files is an array, you can do this:

```
fileNames.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.split('_')[2].localeCompare(b.split('_')[2]);
});
```

Note that you don't need to assign the return value of [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to the array, since [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) works in place. It changes the variable itself.

`.split('_')[2]` splits the string up into an array: `['file', '1', 'abc', '10-23-2015.txt']`, then returns the value at index `2`, which is `'abc'`, this is then used in the sort.